# Any way to access an aspect's target object's field without reflection (given a getter pointcut)?

Tags: java, reflection, aop, aspectj

I've got the following issue that I am trying to solve with AspectJ.

Given an entity class with a null @Embedded field, when trying to access the field with a getter, instantiate it first if it is null.  ie: this will ensure that getXXXX will never return a null value.

For example:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {

        @Id
    private long id;

    @Embedded
    private Validity validity;
}


And Validity:

@Embeddable
public class Validity{
    private long from;
    private long to;
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to best write the before() advice however.  Ideally, I'm trying to avoid using reflection for fear of slowing things down, but so far, the best I have been able to come up with is the following:

```
// define a pointcut for any getter method of a field with @Embedded of type Validity with any name in com.ia.domain package
pointcut embeddedGetter() : get( @javax.persistence.Embedded com.ia.domain.Validity com.ia.domain..* );

before() : embeddedGetter(){
    String fieldName = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    Object obj = thisJoinPoint.getThis();

    // check to see if the obj has the field already defined or is null
    try{
        Field field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        if( field.get(obj) == null )
            field.set(obj, new com.ia.domain.Validity() );
    }
    catch( IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e){}
}
```

But my advice uses reflection to access the field value.  Is there any way to do this without reflection?

Comment: AspectJ doesn't provide this kind of access to the field target. Even if you could get access to the value of the field, how would you re-assign the value when it is null without using reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With around advice you can make the reflection only necessary when initialization is required:

```
Object around(): embeddedGetter() {
    Object value = proceed();
    if (value == null) {
        String fieldName = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        Object obj = thisJoinPoint.getThis();

        try{
            Field field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(obj, value = new Validity() );
        }
        catch( IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e){e.printStackTrace();}           
    }
    return value;
}
```